# Joomla $document->addScriptDeclaration with single quote and double quote

Tags: javascript

Iam struggeling with the situation that I have to use single quotes and double quotes in Joomla $document->addScriptDeclaration.

```
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("a[href="#location").on('shown', function (e) {
            initialize();
        });
    });
');
```

My problem here is the selector which has to be usually addressed with jQuery("a[href="#location"]). Now here is the situation with double quote in double quote.
Changing to single quote is not possible, because the script declaration is within single quotes.

How can I resolve this problem?

The begin of the view is:

```
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

//JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'helpers/html');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive'); 

$document = JFactory::getDocument();

$document->addScriptDeclaration('
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // remove top banner manual because it is a module loaded by list
        jQuery("#top-content-banner").remove();
        jQuery("a[href=\'#location\']").on("shown", function (e) {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    });
');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quotes using backwards slashes like so:

```
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

//JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'helpers/html');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive'); 
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

$document = JFactory::getDocument();

$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a[href=\'#location\']").on("shown", function(e) {
            alert("it has worked");
        });
    }); 
');
```

Note the single quotes I have added too.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried it and copied this into the view, but it does not work. The whole part is not visible anymore.

Comment: @Perino - I've updated my code and also tested it. Works fine for me now. I also added in the closing square bracket `]` which you were missing

Comment: Now, there is no error anymore, Lodder. But the script wont be fired. It is the same issue like my comment to Faris answer.

Comment: @Perino - Have you made sure that bootstrap.js is being loaded on your page? I have honestly tested the code I've provided and it works. I added it to the template index.php but with a few modifications for me, went to go and edit an article in the frontend, and when clicking the correct tab, I got an alert message. Have you ensured you have defined `$document`?

Comment: I've added the begin of the view. The first part of the scropt, the removing part will be done without problems. But the new one will only do with typical <script></script>.

Comment: @Perino - Are you getting any errors on your browser console?

Comment: No errors on the console. If I make a click function on the parent selector, it is the tab navigation, for this function it is no problem. jQuery("#Parent_TabTabs").click(function() {
   alert("Hallo");
  });

Comment: With Joomla declaration, I dont get it to run. If I do it the classic way, it will do.<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('a[href="#location"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  initialize();
    });
});
</script>

Comment: @Perino - I've updated the code in my answer. Try copying it without changing anything, then test to see if you get the alert message

Comment: I've deleted my part and inserted your part Lodder, but still no alert message :-( When I add an additional message before ("a[href=\'#location\']"), 'alert("stage1");' the first alert message will come up!

Comment: Lodder, positive news! I found the problem. Your approach will do. The problem is, that the selector cannot be found, because the Tab will be build later on the script of the view. So when I put the declaration at the end of the script, the function can be fired. The question is, why can it be done with <script></script> at the begin of the view?!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Heredoc string like so:

```
$s = <<<SCRPT
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("a[href='#location']").on('shown', function (e) {
            initialize();
        });
    });
SCRPT;
$document->addScriptDeclaration($s);
```

### Edit

You can test it yourself. It's working:

```
$s = <<<SCRPT
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("a[href='#location']").on('click', function () {
            alert('Yes');
        });
    });
SCRPT;
$document->addScriptDeclaration($s);
echo '<a href="#location">Click Here</a>';
```

Comment: nice approach Fari, but it is not working. Ive tried it with different functions and the script approach is working. But for the selector jQuery("a[href='#location']") with single and double quotes, it is not working.

Comment: It is working. I am going to add the codes for test. The jQuery selector has no issue.

Comment: I have no luck. Im my case "a[href='#location']" is a bootstrap tab. The function should be fired, when the tab a[href='#location'] is clicked. If I put the script in normal <script></script> brackets, it is working. When I put into Joomlas addScriptDeclaration, the function will be not fired.

Comment: Hmm, it's weird.

Comment: @Fari: also your approach can be done! Problem was the same like I explained at Lodders answer. So the alert message can be displayed. But with this approach the script call initiliazie(), a separate function, won't do.

Comment: jQuery `.on()` function can work with dynamically-added elements. The issue can be due to `initialize` function. May it  be `initialise`? What is the scope of the function? Can you use the body of the function instead of `initialize();` and say the result?

Answer (score 2):

Just as another option, though I would recommend other answers over this one, you can also use output buffering to get around the quote issue:

```
ob_start();
// close the php tag, so this would normally just print directly to the page
// output buffering will allow us to capture it and store it in a variable
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a[href='#location']").on('shown', function (e) {
        initialize();
    });
});
<?php
$s = ob_get_clean();
$document->addScriptDeclaration($s);
```